# value not being passed into query

Tags: php, mysql, forms, class

I am having an issue with $homework_date showing up as 0000-00-00 in MySQL. I cannot figure out why... I have been over and over the code and cannot find the error.

Here is the form.

```
<SCRIPT language=Javascript>
       <!--
       function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
       }
       //-->
</SCRIPT>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      altField: "#alt-datepicker",
      altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      dateFormat:   "DD, MM d, yy"
    });
  });
</script>
<?php
require_once('/home/jeremyohmann/www/projects/homework/classes/homework.php');
$homework = new Homework();

$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"Select
  classes.class_name,
  classes.class_id
From
  classes
Where
  classes.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
echo '<p>Add homework to one of your classes below.</p><br />';
echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
echo "<select name='AddHomeworkClass'>";
echo "<option value='' >Select Class</option>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $value=$row['class_name'];
  $id   =$row['class_id'];
  echo "<option value='" . $id . "'>" . $value . "</option>";
  }
echo "</select><br />";
echo "Homework Name: <input type='text' name='AddHomeworkHomework' placeholder='Homework' /><br />";
echo "Total Points Avaliable for Assignment: <input type='text' name='AddHomeworkPointsAvaliable' placeholder='Points Avaliable' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'/><br />";
echo "Points Earned: <input type='text' name='AddHomeworkPointsEarned' placeholder='Points Earned' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'/><br />";
echo "Date: <input type='text' id='datepicker' placeholder='Date'/><br />";
echo "<input type='text' id='alt-datepicker' name='AddHomeworkDate' />";
echo "<input type='submit' name='AddHomework' value='Add Homework' />";
echo "</form>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the class that processes the form.

```
<?php
class Homework {
    private     $db_connection              =null;                      //Database connection
    private     $userID                     ="";                        //User's ID
    private     $class_id                   ="";                        //Class id this homework is from
    private     $homework_name              ="";                        //Homework name
    private     $avaliable_points           ="";                        //Total points that are avaliable on this homework
    private     $earned_points              ="";                        //Score that the homework recieved
    private     $homework_date              ="";                        //Date the homework was turned in

    public      $homework_add_successful    =false;                     

    public      $errors                     =array();                   //Stores error messages
    public      $messages                   =array();                   //Stores other messages


    public function __construct(){
        if (isset($_POST['AddHomework'])) {
            $this->userID   =   $_POST['user_id'];
            $this->add_homework();
            }
    }

    /**
     * add_homework
     *
     * This will handle the whole process of adding homework.
    */

    private function add_homework() {
        if (empty($_POST['AddHomeworkClass'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Please select a class";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['AddHomeworkHomework'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Please type in a name for your homework";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['AddHomeworkPointsAvaliable'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Please type in points avaliable";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['AddHomeworkPointsEarned'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Please type in points earned";
        } elseif ($_POST['AddHomeworkPointsAvaliable'] <= 0) {
            $this->errors[] = "You cannot have negative points avaliable";
        } elseif ($_POST['AddHomeworkPointsEarned'] <= 0) {
            $this->errors[] = "You cannot have negative points earned";
        } elseif ($_POST['AddHomeworkDate'] = "") {
            $this->errors[] = "Please select a date";
        } else {            

            //Create database connection
            $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

            if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

                //Escape Characters
                $this->class_id         =   $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['AddHomeworkClass']);
                $this->homework_name    =   $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['AddHomeworkHomework']);
                $this->avaliable_points =   $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['AddHomeworkAvaliablePoints']);
                $this->earned_points    =   $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['AddHomeworkEarnedPoints']);
                $this->homework_date    =   $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['AddHomeworkDate']);

                //Remove HTML tags
                $this->class_id         =   strip_tags($this->class_name);
                $this->homework_name    =   strip_tags($this->homework_name);
                $this->avaliable_points =   strip_tags($this->avaliable_points);
                $this->earned_points    =   strip_tags($this->earned_points);
                $this->homework_date    =   strip_tags($this->homework_date);

                //cut down data
                $this->class_id         =   substr($this->class_name, 0, 5);
                $this->homework_name    =   substr($this->homework_name, 0, 64);
                $this->avaliable_points =   substr($this->avaliable_points, 0, 5);
                $this->earned_points    =   substr($this->earned_points, 0, 5);

                //Check if homework name already exists
                $query_check_homework   =   $this->db_connection->query
                ("Select
                    homework.homework_name
                From
                    classes Inner Join
                    homework On classes.class_id = homework.class_id
                Where
                    homework.class_id = '".$this->class_id."' And
                    homework.homework_name = '".$this->homework_name."' And
                    classes.user_id = '".$this->user_id."'");

                if ($query_check_homework->num_rows == 1) {
                    $this->errors[] =   "Sorry, You already have homework in this class with that name. Please choose a different name.";
                } else {
                    //write new homework into the datebase
                    $query_new_homework = $this->db_connection->query("INSERT INTO homework (class_id, homework_name, avaliable_points, earned_points, date) VALUES ('".$this->class_id."', '".$this->homework_name."', '".$this->avaliable_points."', '".$this->earned_points."', '".$this->homework_date."')");

                    if (query_new_homework) {
                        $this->messages[] = "Your homework has been successfully added to the database.";
                        $this->homework_add_successful = true;
                    } else {
                        $this->errors[] = "Sorry, your homework was not successfully added to the database. Please go back and try again.";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "Sorry. no database connection.";
                print '<script type="text/javascript">';
                print 'alert("Please enter a class name.")';
                print '</script>';
            }
        }

    if ($this->errors) {
        foreach ($this->errors as $error) {
            print '<script type="text/javascript">';
            print 'alert("'.$error.'")';
            print '</script>';
        }
    }
    if ($this->messages) {
        foreach ($this->messages as $message) {
            print '<script type="text/javascript">';
            print 'alert("'.$message.'")';
            print '</script>';
        }
    }
}

}
?>
```

Comment: It's because of the dateformat, MySql data format is 'Y-m-d'

Answer (score 0):

As the above commenter mentions, the form is taking in a date format that isn't the same as what MySQL expects. Once MySQL receives the date, it doesn't know how to recognize it as a date. Easy fix tho, just make sure the date format you're sending to MySQL is 'Y-m-d'